# Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace the string by another one. Sometimes the source string contains just an open parenthesis and it occurs a crash during the replace:

ie with this string source: "#ABC (testing"

`string = string.replaceAll(src, replacement);`

And the crash is:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern near index XXX
    #ABC (testing
                 ^
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1340)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1324)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:946)
        at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2164)
```

Do you have an idea for this case guys?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Escape `(` in the pattern `"#ABC \\(testing"`

Comment: Ok but how? The source string is not fixed, so how can I replace the open parenthesis?

Comment: src = src.replaceAll(" \\ ( ", " \\\\ (" ); will do the job. Remove all whitespaces in these arguments. If i write it without white spaces, stackoverflow is eating some of them :P

Comment: @GeorgeZ : the syntax is wrong (build failed)

Comment: I updated my comment.

Comment: @anthony Here is a picture of what i mean. https://i.imgur.com/PhCsyk2.png